# Data does not persist to host volume with docker-compose.yml for MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, volumes

Have docker installed on my Mac along with MongoDB image.  When I start the container with volume specified directly in the docker run command, the data gets persisted even after I stop the container.  But the same does not work when I do it via `docker-compose.yml`.  Can someone suggest what's wrong with the `docker-compose.yml` file?

When I do this, the data gets persisted:

`docker run --name mongodb -v /Users/shrap7/projects/mongodb/data:/data/db --rm -d mongo`

But when I try the same with `docker-compose.yml` - it does not persist data.

```
version: '3.4'
services:
    mongodb:
       image: mongo:latest
       container_name: "mongodb"
       volumes:
          - /Users/shrap7/projects/mongodb/data:/data/db
       ports:
          - 27017:27017
```

I tried with double quotes, tried relative path, i.e. `./data:/data/db`, but no luck.  Thank you.

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO! Can you run `docker inspect mongodb` both for the `docker` and `docker-compose` versions and compare the output? Take a look in particular at the `Mounts` section.

Comment: Hi Max, thank you for responding.  I did what you suggested.   The mounts are identical for both except that the Mode is different between the two.  The mode value when used direct commands is empty, that is, "Mode": "", but when used via docker-compose, it says "Mode": "rw".  Does it mean anything?  There is no other difference between the two mounts.

Answer (score 5):

I'm using Windows and I had the same issue today. I found this [gist](https://gist.github.com/ashblue/aa20cd90d2b4609c0b496b66d4153b99)  that shows a mongodb configuration for docker-compose, and it has support for named volumes. I tried using named volumes and it worked for me.

So in your case, you could try the following configuration (with named volumes):

```
services:
    mongodb:
        image: mongo:latest
        container_name: "mongodb"
        volumes:
            - mongodb:/data/db
            - mongodb_config:/data/configdb
        ports:
            - 27017:27017
volumes:
    mongodb:
    mongodb_config:
```